# How to split text with user list of delimiters but enter NA with no match and maintain columns

Tags: r, string, split, tidyr

I have some free text that I split using a list of delimiters with `tidyr`

**The problem**

The problem I have is that if one of the delimiters is missing, rather than entering `NA`, the resulting column is filled with the next match which means it is in the wrong column. How can I fill with `NA` instead (or just empty?)

**Input**

```
textexample<-c("PatientName is Mr B Goode. Referrer Bilbo Baggins Hospital Number 23434B DOB 13/01/77 Findings All good Diagnosis Normal","PatientName is Mr A Notgood. Hospital Number 666666D DOB 13/01/76 Findings All bad Diagnosis Normal")
```

**Function to split**

```
textexample<-data.frame(textexample,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
delim<-c("PatientName","Referrer","Hospital Number","DOB","Findings","Diagnosis")
textexample<-textexample %>% 
  tidyr::separate(textexample, into = c("added_name",delim), 
                  sep = paste(delim, collapse = "|"),
                  extra = "drop", fill = "right")
```

**Desired output**

```
 added_name                    PatientName        Referrer Hospital Number        DOB   Findings Diagnosis
1                           is Mr B Goode.   Bilbo Baggins          23434B   13/01/77   All good     Normal
2                           is Mr A Notgood.                        666666D        13/01/76    All bad      Normal      <NA>
```

**Current Output**

```
 added_name                    PatientName        Referrer Hospital Number        DOB   Findings Diagnosis
1                           is Mr B Goode.   Bilbo Baggins          23434B   13/01/77   All good     Normal
2                           is Mr A Notgood.    666666D           13/01/76    All bad     Normal      <NA>
```

Comment: You might find it easier to use `sub` to do this, e.g. `output$PatientName <- sub("Patientname(.*?)Referrer", "\\1", textexample)`. That will give you more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Put some separation in the data:

```
a=gsub(pattern = paste0("(",delim,")",collapse = "|"),
        replacement = ";\\1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6;",
       x= paste0(textexample,";"))

b= paste0("(?<=",delim,";).*?(?=;)")
```

then extract the values:

```
  map2_dfc(a,list(b),~str_extract(.x,.y)%>%trimws)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  `1`            `2`             
  <chr>          <chr>           
1 is Mr B Goode. is Mr A Notgood.
2 Bilbo Baggins  NA              
3 23434B         666666D         
4 13/01/77       13/01/76        
5 All good       All bad         
6 Normal         Normal
```

or you can do:

```
cross2(a,b)%>% 
   invoke_map_chr(str_extract, .)%>%
   matrix(length(a))%>%
   data.frame()  
                  X1              X2        X3         X4         X5      X6
1    is Mr B Goode.   Bilbo Baggins    23434B   13/01/77   All good   Normal
2  is Mr A Notgood.             <NA>  666666D   13/01/76    All bad   Normal
```